# COM Exception with Hummingbird DM API x64

Tags: exception, com, opentext

I have a web application which severs as a SAML bridge to Authenticate between the Google Search Appliance and Hummingbird. I am using the Open Text eDOCS DM 5.1 Extensions (x84) PCDClient.dll to connect

For some reason I keep getting

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BAE80C14- D2AC- 11D0 - 8384 - 00A0C92018F4} failed due to the following error: 80040154

When my code makes a call to a login function in the API.

```
login = new PCDLogin();
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

That's a 'Class not Registered' error.  You may need to reinstall the software that created the COM object or use some other method to ensure that the CLSID is there.

If you check the registry for

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BAE80C14- D2AC- 11D0 - 8384 - 00A0C92018F4}
```

to see if it exists it will give you an idea.

HKCR\CLSID is the registry of 64-bit COM objects, and HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID is the registry of 32-bit COM objects. A 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL into its address space; that's why the two registries are separate.

If the object you're looking for is 64bit but you are trying to load it from 32-bit client, you would get this error.

Comment: I have reinstalled the API but I still can't find the reg key location. Its not present at location HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\